# create Grid lines like Geogebra in C#

Tags: c#, math, plot

this is my first step to write my program that can plotter mathematics functions  for that :
i need to create grid lines for the coordinate X and Y 
and specifically those line zooming in/out and half of line disappear exactly like in GeoGebra Graphics when you zoom out with you mouse-wheel ,

i already wrote a simple code in C# in visual Studio   but i cant do like GeoGebra :)  this is my result

[image]

my goal is zoom in/out like this GeoGebra Screenshot

[image]

i can't find how can i do that , any kind of help ?

Comment: Your question is too broad. It seems like you simply should be making your interval between lines a function of the zoom level. But what code have you tried to do that. What's the point of posting code with an empty loop? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? And not for nothing, but when you post code like that, with all those useless, space-eating blank lines, it really discourages people from wanting to bother looking at the code and helping.

Comment: i remove the code

Comment: Removing the code doesn't improve the post. _Improving_ the code, by removing unnecessary code (if any), and removing extra blank lines (i.e. leaving only the bare minimum of what's needed to help readability) would improve the post.

Comment: Thank you Mr Peter  for advice  , i will try